# Weighted sum of measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(M, \mathfrak A)$ be a measurable space, let $(\nu_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ be a collection of measures on $\mathfrak A$ and let $(\beta_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ be a collection of numbers in $[0, \infty]$.  Then the weighted sum of the measures
$$
\nu =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \beta_n\nu_n
$$ 
is also a measure on $\mathfrak A$.

**Question:**

Can this somehow be extended to an uncountable collection of measures?

Comment: Probably yes - assume the measures are parameterized by a real number $x$ instead of by an integer $n$ and integrate instead of summing. Just a comment not an answer since I haven't thought through the argument. The integration need not be with respect to Lebesgue measure. Another measure on the line would weight the "summands" differently.

Comment: See [Choquet Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choquet_theory)